# Multistable systems and their chaotic attractors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory

Let's assume we have a multistable dynamical system

$\dot{x}=F(x)$

Furhter assume it has at least two (chaotic) attractors $A_1,A_2$ with basins of attraction $B(A_1),B(A_2)$.

How much information about the attractor $A_2$ is stored in the basin of attraction of attractor $B(A_1)$ and the attractor $A_1$ itself.

---

To specify what I mean by 'information'. Assuming there exist a perfect algorithm wich can find the ODE describing the attractor 1 $A_1$. If I now start the ODE with an initial condition in $B(A_2)$, will the system evolve into $A_2$ and how well will it describe $A_2$?

---

Possible example of two chaotic attractors:

[image: Attractor 1]
[image: Attractor 2]

Comment: You would have to demand some kind of structural similarity, for instance "polynomial of minimal degree". Otherwise you can ($C^1$-)modify the vector field outside $B(A_1)$ arbitrarily, so that only the algebraic-topological invariants like winding/covering numbers of the boundary and their consequences on the vector field remain constant, provided they exist.

Comment: Is there some literature you can refer me to considering the similar strucutre

Comment: Not really for the sources. Long ago I read a book where semi-random computational trees with parameters were constructed, then fitting the parameters to the existing data, pruning the tree and randomly adding additional branches or knots. Today one would call that an unstructured neural network or similar. // One could restrict that method to polynomial operations and try to find a minimal tree. Or one could learn the vector field via a modern version of neural network where the non-linear operations are only tanh and relu (aka maximum with 0).

Comment: Recently I read about the not so recent theory of the Koopman operator (take a basis of the function space over the state space, then the evolution of the basis under the state dynamic leads to a linear operator, explore left and right eigenvectors etc.). There are ANN approaches to learn the matrix along with an adapted subset of basis functions that are almost eigenfunctions. /// However applying this learned or fitted vector field/propagator outside the learning set is still extrapolation with all the associated pitfalls and uncertainties.